# How do I properly setup and deploy a private API exclusively for my frontend?

Tags: node.js, rest, server

I am currently working on a web application. The client is designed in Vue.js and the server application is made with node.js and express.

As of now I plan to deploy both the client-website and the node.js-app on the same server. Both will be adressed via two different, unique domains. The server will be set up manually with nginx.

The problem now is that this solution won't prevent a user from being able to send requests to the server outside the client that was made for it. Someone will be able to call the /register route (with postman, curl etc.) to create an account an 'unofficial' way. I think the only clean solution is that only my Vue.js-app would be able to perform such actions. However, since both the server and the client are two different environments/applications, some sort of cross-origin-request mechanism (cors for instance) must be set up.

So I'm wondering, is this bad by design or is it usual that way? If I wanted this not to be possible, should I see to that issue and try to make the express-API as private as possible? If so, what are usual best practices for development and deployment / things to consider? Should I change my plan and work on a complete different architecture for my expectations instead / How do 'bigger' sites manage to allow no requests outside the official, public developer API's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the only clean solution is that only my Vue.js-app would be able to perform such actions.

An API that is usable from a browser-based application is just open to the world. You cannot prevent use from other places. That just how the WWW works. You can require that a user in your system is authenticated and that auth credential is provided with each request (such as an auth cookie) before the API will provide any data. But, even then, any hacker can sign up for your system, take the auth credential and use your API for their own uses. You cannot prevent that.

> If I wanted this not to be possible, should I see to that issue and try to make the express-API as private as possible?

There is no such thing as a private API that is used from a browser-based application.  Nothing that runs in a browser is private.

If you were thinking of using CORs protections to limit the use of your API, that only limits it from other browser-based applications as CORs protections are enforced inside the browser.  Any outside script using your API is not subject to CORs at all.

> How do 'bigger' sites manage to allow no requests outside the official, public developer API's?

Bigger sites (such as Google) have APIs that require some sort of developer credential and that credential comes with particular usage rules (max number of requests over some time period, max data used, storage limits, etc...).  These sites implement code in their API servers to verify that only an authorized client (one with the proper developer credential) is using the API and that the usage stays within the bounds that are afforded that developer credential.  If not, the API will return some sort of 4xx or 5xx error.

> Someone will be able to call the /register route (with postman, curl etc.) to create an account an 'unofficial' way.

Yes, this will likely be possible.  Many sites nowadays use something like a captcha to require human intervention before a request to create an account can succeed.  This can be successful at preventing entirely automated creation of accounts.  But, it still doesn't stop some developer from manually creating an account, then grabbing that accounts credentials and using them with your API.

> When talking about web applications, the only truly private APIs are APIs that are entirely within your server (one part of your server calling something in another part of your server).  These private APIs can even be http requests, but they must either not be accessible to the outside world or they must require credentials that are never available to the outside world.  Since they are not available to the outside world, they cannot be used from within a browser application.

> OK, that was a lot of things you cannot do, what CAN you do?

First and foremost, an application design that keeps private APIs internal to the server (not sent from the client) is best.  So, if you want to implement a piece of functionality that needs to call several APIs you would like to be private, then don't implement that functionality on the client.  Implement that functionality on the server.  Have the client make one request and get some data or HTML back that it can then display.  Keep as much of the internals of the implementation of that feature on the server.

Second, you can require auth credentials for a user in your system for all API usage.  While this won't prevent rouge usage, it will give you a bit more control because you can track usage, suspend user accounts when you find abuse, etc...

Third, you can implement usage rules for your public-facing APIs such as requests per minute, amount of data, etc... that your actual web application would never exceed so if they are exceeded, then it must be some unintended usage of the API.  And, you could go further than that and detect usage patterns that do not happen in your client.  For example, if you see an API user cycling through dozens of users, requesting all their profiles and you know that is something your regular client never does, you could detect that type of usage and block it.